Conditional Formatting on a 2D Spilled Range
I have a table Data on sheet1 containing data that is being reference in a Python formula cell on sheet2. The python cell returns the excel value of a newly created DataFrame which spills into a 2D spilled range. The idea is the highlight the entire row of the spilled range, which would be a defined length, based on the value in the 4th column.
Target Goal
There is a styler object and methods in the pandas library that is already imported within the excel python initialization, but I have not been able to get it to return the object with the styling.
I have been able to get the first column where the spilled range originates to highlight by using this formula =AND(ROW(F1)=MEDIAN(ROW(F1), MIN(ROW(F$4#)),MAX(ROW(F$4#))), I1=[condition]) with the spilled range being in F4.
Currently what happens

What happens if you change both F$4# into $F$4# ?

No changes occur, it looks like the extra columns are treated as empty cells

What is [condition]?

It's just any parameter that I'm looking for. It's a value check

But if you refer to it as I1=[condition] than it would be I1:M4=[condition] or something like that. Is that the intention? Can't see that from what you shared.
